# Can I get instance dynamically by type or class name using Ninject

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, ninject, bind

```
void Start () {
    IKernel nKernel = new StandardKernel();
    nKernel.Bind<IAnimal>().To(typeof(Dog)).Named("Dog");
    nKernel.Bind<IAnimal>().To(typeof(Cat)).Named("Cat");

    IAnimal animalInst = nKernel.Get<IAnimal>("Dog");
    Debug.LogError($"{animalInst.Name}");
    IAnimal  animalInst2 = nKernel.Get<IAnimal>("Cat");
    Debug.LogError($"{animalInst.Name}");
}
```

I want instantiate IAnimal's sub class in runtime dynamically, I tried to run this code but it occur Error on
"IAnimal  animalInst2 = nKernel.Get("Cat");" =>
ActivationException: Error activating float
No matching bindings are available, and the type is not self-bindable.
How can I bind subclasses on one interface? and can i get it by class type or class name?

Answer (score 0):

It appears your `Cat` class has a constructor with a `float` parameter. Ninject cannot resolve this dependency since value types are not self-bindable.

You could add `.WithConstructorArgument` to your binding:

```
nKernel.Bind<IAnimal>().To(typeof(Cat))
    .WithConstructorArgument("myFloatArgName", 0)
    .Named("Cat");
```

Or look at using a [provider](https://github.com/ninject/Ninject/wiki/Providers,-Factory-Methods-and-the-Activation-Context).